# what are the necessary steps to transfer the mastership of the clearcase stream to different location?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I created one stream and now I would like to know the procedure to transfer the mastership of the stream in a different location? what are the steps should I follow?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by following "[Transferring mastership of a stream](https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_admin.doc/t_transfer_stream_mship.htm)"

> In some cases, you must manually change mastership of branch types or activities associated with a stream.
>   The output of the `chmaster` command includes a list of these objects.
>   The output may also include an instruction to run the `chmaster –stream` command with the `-override` option. This option transfers mastership of objects whose mastership was not transferred during the original invocation of the command.
>
> For example, to transfer mastership of the stream v2.1.bl5 and its associated objects to the boston_hub replica:

```
multitool chmaster -stream boston_hub@/vobs/dev stream:v2.1.bl5@/vobs/dev
```

> **Attention**: Do not use `-override` unless the output of `chmaster –stream` indicates that you should do so.

---

This is part of the more general section "[Changing mastership of VOB objects](https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_admin.doc/c_chg_vob_obj_mship.htm)", and based on the [`multitool chmaster` command](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cqhelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearquest.ms_admin.doc/cmd_reference/mu_chmaster.htm).

This is also part of procedures like "[To deliver to a nonmastered target stream (MultiSite)](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/t_delvr_to_nonmast_trgt_ms.htm)".